# "django_site" does not exist on migration

Tags: python, django

Earlier today I was having some problems with conflicting migrations for various reasons.  I decided to just destroy the entire DB and start from scratch (we're pretty early in the project there is no harm in resetting everything).  However, when I tried to get things back up and running with `manage.py migrate` I get this error:

```
File "/Users/travis/Documents/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 84, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
psycopg2.errors.UndefinedTable: relation "django_site" does not exist
LINE 1: ..."django_site"."domain", "django_site"."name" FROM "django_si...
                                                             ^


The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):

  ...

    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: relation "django_site" does not exist
LINE 1: ..."django_site"."domain", "django_site"."name" FROM "django_si...
                                                             ^
```

This seems to be a very common error and the main solutions I have seen (and tried) are:

1. add `SITE_ID = 1` to base.py; in my case, it's already in there.
2. Include   `"django.contrib.sites"` earlier in `DJANGO_APPS` I've tried putting it first and got the same error.
3. run `manage.py migrate sites` before other migrations; running this migration gives me the same error.

Additionally, I have completely removed the DB, and created a new PGSQL instance,  I've removed the project locally and cloned it from our repo. I've tried creating new venvs in different locations. I've reinstalled Django.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally hit with a flash of inspiration after 5+ hours of poking around.  In one of the apps there was a `utils.py` file with a variable `domain = Site.objects.get_current().domain`.  Since there was no `Site` table yet it could not get `Site` objects...  Not really sure why this was a problem initializing the DB from scratch when it wouldn't have a problem getting- say `Users` but perhaps there is something unique about `Sites`.